# Excel Formula or VBA: Find match's address in separate table with 2 column criteria - No helper columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

I need help with formula structure,

I have 2 tables. I would like to find a match where column a & column b equal and get the address in table 2. They will be unique entries. So for example:

ProjectInfoTable :

```
         A      |       B      |     C     |
  ------------------------------------------
1 |     Name    |    Company   |  Project  |
  ------------------------------------------
2 | Chris Evans |     Apple    |   Info    |
  ------------------------------------------
3 | Chris Evans |    Google    |   Info    |
  ------------------------------------------
4 | Bill Gates  |  Burger King |   Info    |
  ------------------------------------------
```

ClientInfoTable:

```
         A      |       B      |   C   |   D
  -------------------------------------------
1 |    Client   |    Company   |  Age  |  Sex | 
  -------------------------------------------
2 | Chris Evans |     Apple    |   12  |   M  |
  -------------------------------------------
3 | Chris Evans |    Google    |   17  |   M  |
  -------------------------------------------
4 | Bill Gates  |  Burger King |   98  |   F  |
  -------------------------------------------
```

**I would like to be able to, while in 'ProjectInfoTable', get the address of the matching Name & Company client in 'ClientInfoTable'**

The trouble I'm running into is there could be a thousand different Chris Evans out there, so VLOOKUP isn't good here. I need to make sure it's the same Chris Evans in 'ClientInfoTable' that I'm looking at in 'ProjectInfoTable' by cross-referencing their companies

I can get the address no problem if I only search it by name:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(ClientInfoTable,MATCH([@[Client]],ClientInfoTable[Client],0),1)),COLUMN(INDEX(ClientInfoTable,MATCH([@[Client]],ClientInfoTable[Client],0),1)),1,1,"Clients")
```

but I need to add an additional condition of their companies so now that formula is useless.

Any ideas out there? I don't want to use hidden columns, or 'helper columns'

I will except VBA or formula based answers. I'll even reward a bounty to anyone who can provide both, assuming that the data will always be dynamic ranges, **and** then gives a good explanation of your code/formula. I am here to learn, I am not a copy/paste type of user, explanations go a long with me.

Comment: Please update the question with a small sample of the desired output.

Comment: Sure, I can @Gary'sStudent - the output would simply be the address, or range of match in `ClientInfoTable`, vba or otherwise. There's really no right way or desired way, as long as it works. I'll edit my title to reflect that

Comment: Agree with @Gary'sStudent - you need to state if you need a column D in your `ProjectInfo` table with e.g. ages from the `ClientInfo` table?

Comment: `ProjectInfoTable` and `ClientInfoTable` tables are nothing alike, aside from Name & Company, that's why I need to be able to get the address in `ClientInfoTable` of the match. I'll clarify in an edit

Comment: I personally don't see how that would benefit any future question seekers @SMeaden when the question is tagged with VBA related tags and the title states VBA. But I am also not here to be an officer of answers. It could help someone you never know. The only reason I have a bounty is to provide an existing answer with credit as I stated I would if someone met the outlined requirements. I just can't give it away immediately, SO makes you wait 24 hours to give the actual amount away so I'm just stuck in limbo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `AutoFilter()`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim rng As Range

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ClientInfoTable").Range '<--| reference 'ClientInfoTable' range
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Chris Evans" '<--| filter it on its 1st column with "Chris Evans"
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="Google" '<--| filter it on its 2nd column with "Google"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
            Set rng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1) '<--| if any filtered cells other than header then set the range corresponding to upleftmost filtered cell below the headers row
            MsgBox "Found at " & rng.Address
        End If
        .AutoFilter '<--| show rows back visible
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, this is one way to do it for VBA, damn, I should have recorded a macro before even putting this question up. Although, there will always ONLY be 1 match, this might help someone in the future. It would be interesting to see if there is a good formula answer for those users not allowed to use VBA documents, per company policy etc. I'll give you credit for the right answer just because you were first. Thanks

Comment: As a side note for anyone that doesn't know: setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` to False will stop the actual animation perform

Answer (score 7):

### Formula:

Here's a formula only solution with no hidden/ helper columns and no array formulas:

```
=ADDRESS(
    ROW(
        ClientInfo
    ) - 1 +
    MATCH(
        1,
        INDEX(
            --INDEX(
                ClientInfo[Client] = $A5,
                0
            ) *
            --INDEX(
                ClientInfo[Company] = $B5,
                0
            ),
            0
        ),
        0
    ),
    COLUMN(ClientInfo)
)
```

### Components:

**a** `--INDEX(ClientInfo[Client]=$A5,0)` - returns a boolean array for as many matches there are for e.g. `Chris Evans` in `ClientInfo[Client]`. In the example below this will be `{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}`. This is then cast to array of integer with the double unary operator to leave `{1,1,0,0}`

**b** `--INDEX(ClientInfo[Company]=$B5,0)` - same thing as **a** e.g. `Apple` in `ClientInfo[Company]` in the example is the array `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}` - which is then cast to `{1,0,0,1}`

**c** `INDEX(a*b,0)` - multiples elements 1..n of array **a** with elements 1..n of array **b**. In our example this results in `{1,0,0,0}` *and at this point you have identified your matching composite key for Chris Evans and Apple as being the 1st row of ClientInfo*

**d** `MATCH(1,c,0)` - gets the index of the 1 in the array which in our example of Chris Evans and Apple is 1. You mentioned *They will be unique entries* so I don't think we have a problem here.

**e** `ROW(ClientInfo)-1+d` -  I defined `ClientInfo` as a Table/ ListObject with a range of `A8:D12` but the reference is giving back `A9:D12` which seems to be the way it works the named ranges for Tables/ ListObjects. So we need to deduct one from the `ROW` of that range to get the start of the offset; then simply add the result of **d**.

**f** `ADDRESS(e,COLUMN(ClientInfo))` - returns the cell address of **e** and the first column of `ClientInfo` table.

### Example:

[image]

### VBA:

Using the example above, the VBA method will do the following:

1. Assume no match found
2. Iterate the rows of the table
3. Get the candidate values and check against the inputs for the columns referenced
4. If both match then quit the loop returning the address

The code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    MsgBox GetAddressOfKey("Client", "Chris Evans", "Company", "Apple", "ClientInfo")
    MsgBox GetAddressOfKey("Client", "Chris Evans", "Company", "Google", "ClientInfo")
    MsgBox GetAddressOfKey("Client", "Bill Gates", "Company", "Burger King", "ClientInfo")

End Sub

Function GetAddressOfKey(col1 As String, val1 As String, col2 As String, val2 As String, strTable As String) As String

    Dim lst As ListObject
    Dim lr As ListRow
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strCandidate1 As String
    Dim strCandidate2 As String

    strAddress = ""
    Set lst = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(strTable)

    'iterate rows
    For Each lr In lst.ListRows
        'get candidate values
        strCandidate1 = Intersect(lr.Range, lst.ListColumns(col1).Range).Value
        strCandidate2 = Intersect(lr.Range, lst.ListColumns(col2).Range).Value
        'check against inputs
        If strCandidate1 = val1 And strCandidate2 = val2 Then
            strAddress = lst.Range.Cells(lr.Index + 1, 1).Address
            'quit if we find a match
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lr

    'return
    GetAddressOfKey = strAddress

End Function
```

PS I was hesitant to provide the VBA answer as well as you already accepted a decent answer. However, I have a slight preference for doing this without updating the UI although I agree the `AutoFilter` method is good enough. HTH

Comment: This is gorgeous!!! @Robin thank you so much. Im really glad you included a VBA answer. I really didn't want to use an interface altering method because I have data next to the table that disappears when the table filters, but that's easy to circumvent with `ScreenUpdating`. Additionally, its just good SO etiquette to mark him correct, because, well, he wasn't wrong. I'll award you some bounty when it lets me because you did everything I asked to earn it. The formula is brilliant and thanks for explaining it. I didn't know about double unary operator!!! I'm gonna learn about that this week.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach your problem is to use the SQL support in Excel VBA via ADODB. This [Microsoft article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx) explains how to do this.

Using the SQL support, you basically have two options: either you write a functions in VBA that returns the (first) value for a given name and company from the `ClientInfoTable`, using a `SELECT` statement, or you write a sub in VBA that directly inserts the values for all row in `ProjectInfoTable` wherever you need them, using a join between the `ProjectInfoTable` and the `ClientInfoTable` on the name and the company.

Comment: This feels like overkill to me, personally, but doesn't mean its a bad answer. It could help someone out a lot, especially those who are well versed in SQL language

Comment: Forgive me @soulshined but this is indeed a classic SQL problem with a simple `INNER JOIN` between both tables. With ODBC, Excel can query worksheets and ranges within worksheets, even across workbooks. A faster, scalable, efficient, maintainable solution without `for` loops or nested formulas. These others are arguably overkill! But to each his own.

Comment: @Parfait I absolutely see the benefits of it now. I actually saw the benefits only a few days after this question lol I have a new question up with a bounty if you care to share your thoughts http://stackoverflow.com/a/41800303/2353523

Comment: I arrived here from your bounty. Your multiple matches is just dynamic SQL. Screenshots indicate you use Excel for Mac, requiring [ODBC driver download](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ODBC-drivers-that-are-compatible-with-Excel-for-Mac-9FA6BC7F-D19E-4F7F-9BE4-92E85C77D712). Consider learning this useful special-purpose language where mostly all programmers use at some point.

Comment: @Parfait  I'm quite familiar with SQL, but not familiar with VBA or how the languages coexist yet. VBA is my 2017 new years  resolution in challenging myself to learn a new language. So I'm slowly getting into the heart of things.  I use 2016 excel (32bit) on Win 10 btw don't know why it looks like Mac version?

Comment: Disregard. That particular snapshot was off my iPhone. I posted the question on-the-go

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function I wrote.Put it to any module in the file where you want to use:

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit
Public Function doubleMatch(criteria1 As Range, criteria1_Range As Range, criteria2 As Range, criteria2_Range As Range) As Long
Dim crit1 As Variant, crit2 As Variant
Dim crit1_ARR(), crit2_ARR() 'Arrays where criteria ranges are stored
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim u1 As Long, l1 As Long

crit1_ARR = criteria1_Range.Value2
crit2_ARR = criteria2_Range.Value2
crit1 = criteria1.Value
crit2 = criteria2.Value

doubleMatch = -1
'checking if ranges have the same height
If (UBound(crit1_ARR) <> UBound(crit2_ARR)) Then
    GoTo endFunc
End If

'checking if ranges are one col wide
If (LBound(crit1_ARR, 2) <> UBound(crit1_ARR, 2)) Then
    GoTo endFunc
End If

If (LBound(crit2_ARR, 2) <> UBound(crit2_ARR, 2)) Then
    GoTo endFunc
End If

l1 = LBound(crit1_ARR)
u1 = UBound(crit1_ARR)

For i = l1 To u1
    If (crit1 = crit1_ARR(i, 1)) Then
        If (crit2 = crit2_ARR(i, 1)) Then
            doubleMatch = i + Abs(l1 = 0) * 1
            GoTo endFunc
        End If
    End If
Next i

endFunc:

End Function
```

Example of usage:
[image]

In case of error it returns -1; otherwise it returns number of row where it matches.

If you want the full address, you can use this function together with ADDRESS and MATCH functions:

```
=ADDRESS(doubleMatch(H2;A:A;I2;B:B);MATCH("Client";A:A;0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, someone beat ya to it though

Answer (score 0):

You can combine VLookUp with Choose to have more than one criteria. In your example:

```
=VLookUp(A1&","&B1, Choose({1.2}, ClientInfoTable!A1:A4&","&ClientInfoTable!B1:B4,ClientInfoTable!C1:C4), 2, False)
```

This is a matrix formula so you have to close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What happens is the following: the choose-function chooses the first and second value that it is given (that's what the first argument {1.2} says). As this is a matrix formula you get not only one pair of values but one for each row. In this example you get a matrix:

```
A-----------------------|B----------
Chris Evans, Apple      |12
Chris Evans, Google     |17
Bill Gates, Burger King |98
```

This is the matrix you can now use for VLookUp.

You should make sure that the delimiter (comma in this example) does not occur in your data.

If you only need the address and not the actual values, use the function Match instead of vlookup:

```
=Match(A1&","B1, Choose({1.2}, ClientInfoTable!A1:A4&","&B1:B4,ClientInfoTable!C1:C4))
```

This returns the row the corresponding set is in within the given matrix. If the matrix does not begin in row 1 you have to add the matrix-position.

Comment: This is a very nice unique formula solution. I would just ask you actually change it and get the address since that was my only requirement I had. But it's a nice demonstration of choose. You should also fix the syntax for your formula - `ClientInfoTable!` might confuse some new comers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a VBA function that takes the clientname and company as string arguments - then loops through the clients table and return the address if found. Below code will return "Not found#" if there is no match

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Function SearchAddress(clientName As String, company As String) As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim shtClients As Worksheet
    Set shtClients = Sheets("Clients") 'Clients = name of the sheet with ClientTableInfo
    x = 2

    'loop through the clients table searching for the row where the clientname and companyname is what is supplied to the function

    Do
        'Column A has ClientName of ClientTableInfo
        'Column B has companyName of ClientTableInfo
        '.............
        'Column E has Address of ClientTableInfo <-- our search target
        If shtClients.Range("A" & x).Value = clientName And shtClients.Range("B" & x).Value = company Then
            SearchAddress = shtClients.Range("E" & x).Value 'column E has the address in the clients info table
            Exit Function
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until x > shtClients.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    SearchAddress = "Not found#"
End Function
```

To use this function import the code into a macro workbook as a VBA module (remember to enable macros). Then type the formula into an cell like a normal excel formula

```
=SearchAddress(ProjectInfoTable[@Name],ProjectInfoTable[@Company])
```

or

```
=SearchAddress(A1,A2)
```